# Shortcut is not getting added to the Start Menu when using WiX Toolset

Tags: .net, wix, windows-installer

I am building a custom .msi file using the WiX toolset.

I want to create a shortcut for my application in the Start Menu folder and on the Desktop. I currently have the following XML code:

```
<StandardDirectory Id="DesktopFolder">
    <Component
        Id="ApplicationShortcutDesktop"
        Guid="{*}">
        <Shortcut Id="ApplicationDesktopShortcut"
            Name="App"
            Description="AppDescription"
            Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]App.exe"
            WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER"/>
        <RemoveFolder Id="DesktopFolder" On="uninstall"/>
        <RegistryValue
            Root="HKCU"
            Key="Software\Company\App"
            Name="installed"
            Type="integer"
            Value="1"
            KeyPath="yes"/>
    </Component>
</StandardDirectory>

<StandardDirectory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
    <Component Id="ApplicationShortcutStartMenu" Guid="{*}">
        <Shortcut Id="ApplicationShortcutStartMenu"
            Name="App"
            Description="AppDescription"
            Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]App.exe"
            WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER"/>
        <RemoveFolder Id="ProgramMenuFolder" On="uninstall"/>
        <RegistryValue
            Root="HKCU"
            Key="Software\Company\App"
            Name="installed"
            Type="integer"
            Value="1"
            KeyPath="yes"/>
    </Component>
</StandardDirectory>
```

I am referencing the shortcuts in the `<Feature>` element like this:

```
<Feature Id="Main">
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProjectOutputFiles"/>

    <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationShortcutDesktop"/>
    <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationShortcutStartMenu"/>
</Feature>
```

It works fine for the Desktop shortcut, but not for the Start Menu shortcut. It should perhaps also be noted that everything else works fine, i.e. the .exe file is running as it should etc.

I am using WiX v4.

Can anyone spot what the issue might be? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't immediately see anything wrong, but I cover this topic step by step in the [Deployment Dojo - Episode 24](https://www.youtube.com/live/1kV4gk3tTzg). I don't know how to summarize that whole video for StackOverflow, but it works in that episode, so it should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply (and for WiX).

I looked a bit more into it, and the shortcut does get added to the Start Menu, just not in the "Recently added" section. 

It doesn't seem like this topic is covered in the video link you sent me - do you know more about how I could add the shortcut to the "Recently added" section?

Comment: "Recently added" is controlled by Windows not your installation package. I've seen it stop updating in test scenarios when you install/uninstall a few times.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably simply your code above. You are also prompting to remove the shortcut which isn't necessary as WIX will handle this for you on uninstall automatically.

You could declare your StandardDirectory separately like below. You can declare your INSTALLFOLDER variable here as well.

```
<StandardDirectory Id="ProgramFiles6432Folder">
    <!-- Create a folder within the parent folder given the name -->
    <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="!(bind.Property.Manufacturer)\!(bind.Property.ProductName)" />
</StandardDirectory>
```

Then in a separate fragment declare your app and its shortcuts like so

```
<Fragment>
<ComponentGroup Id="MyAppInstall" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
 <Component Id="AppExecutable" Bitness="always64">            
  <File Id="AppExecutable" Source="MyApp.exe"/>   
  <Shortcut Name="My App Name" Directory="ProgramMenuFolder" Advertise="yes" Icon="MyApp.exe"/>
  <Shortcut Name="My App Name" Directory="DesktopFolder" Advertise="yes" Icon="MyApp.exe"/>
 </Component>
</ComponentGroup>
```

Declaring the Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" will be passed to the shortcut components automatically.